# Best practice for where to define exception handling and error logging in ASP.NET MVC applications?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, exception, error-handling

In your typical MVC application, you have many layers.

Database layer
Model layer (possibly in the same package as the DB)
View/UI Layer
Controller Layer
Business Layer

Where should the exception handling or error logging live here, if you were to create custom exceptions, interfaces and models for error logging in a sufficiently complex MVC application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle exceptions in your data layer that come from your data layer (SQLExceptions, for example), in your controller for controller/logic exceptions, and in your view for display related exceptions.  Use a logging solution like ELMAH to log exceptions and catch unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Right, the baked in things just don't cut it when you are debugging a random ghost in the machine that only happens on a single production server! Definitely best answer here, Elmah is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Elmah on my site at work with good success.

http://www.dotneat.net/2011/04/12/ErrorHandlingInASPNETMVC3.aspx

http://joel.net/logging-errors-with-elmah-in-asp.net-mvc-3--part-1--setup